# Suspend mode does not work Dell 14 7000 series

Tags: nvidia, suspend, dell, shutdown

I'm having a little problem here. I have a Dell 14 7000 with nvidia geforce 940mx graphic card. The problem is the suspended mode does not work properly. When press the button and choose to suspend, it shuts down. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. 
I've already searched a lot, i did not figure out how to solve this.